# touchscreen monitor to macmini - can it do multitouch, swipe, expand, etc?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm trying to create a iPad-type of app (say using a Mac App), except something that works on a large touchscreen (say 32" monitor) that is attached to a MacMini.

1) Is it possible to get iPad-type of actions (multitouch, swipe, expand, etc.) via this setup? 
2)Would I need extra drivers, etc for the touchscreen monitor to communicate whats happening (multitouch, swipe, expand, etc) to the MacMini?

Thank you!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac, Apple's Magic Trackpad supports multi-touch gestures. Cocoa has support for them, too.

The touchscreen's driver will need to support multi-touch, as will, for that matter, the hardware itself.

It appears that a few multi-touch LCD monitors exist, but I didn't happen to find one with a Mac OS driver.

Comment: Noa, Thanks for the quick response. Which monitor did you end up choosing for your project? Do you have a link to your project by chance, would love to learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: I've used touch screens with Mac OS, and browsed some of the multi-touch APIs, but unfortunately the projects I've done were for iOS. I haven't used a multi-touch flatscreen on Mac OS.